# Node.js child_process.exect stdout return null, but stderr did not

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, child-process, stderr

Currently, I have this simple code that executes `java -version` to the command line to check if the user has installed Java.

Odd, that when I run this code, `stdout` gives me nothing, but `stderr` gives me my desired result.

```js
cprocess.execSync("java -version", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log("stdout: " + stdout); // nothing
  console.log("stderr: " + stderr); // output: java version
}
```

Why is this happening? Do I need to change anything in `exec` options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execSync` doesn't take a callback argument, but `exec` does. The text of the question references `exec`, while the code snippet you shared references `execSync`, so I'm guessing you meant `exec`.

Assuming you really meant to use `exec`, the callback is correct, and the issue isn't with the code, but the `java -version` command you're calling - that command outputs the information to stderr, not stdout. You could redirect it, but to be honest, I wouldn't bother - you could just use the stderr output.

Comment: Awesome answer, how can I redirect it thought? I'd love to know!!

Comment: @ABC you could use the `shell` option, and then redirect using the native shell's syntax. E.g., on *nix - `java -version 2>&1`.